# Using the Application object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble using the Application object. I am from Classic ASP so I know how to use it there, global.asa, etc, so can someone explain to me how to use it in MVC?

In my Global.Asax it looks like this:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        Application.Add("Version", 1); // I want to add this
    }
}
```

Then how do I access it my code?

I tried this in both a controller and view:

```
using System.Web;

int Version = Application["Version"];
```

and got a compilation error in both:

**The name 'Application' does not exist in the current context**

Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you getting a cast error?  Try: `int Version = (int)Application["Version"];`

Comment: Well.... where is that code in?  If you put that code in a controller action method, it should work with the cast.  But if you literally have it as you do, yes, that would be problematic because Application is a property of the HttpContext, and you would need to get the current context to check the collection.

Answer (score -1):

Try accessing it this way:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Application["Version"] = 1;
```

Comment: Accessing or defining?

Comment: You should be able to infer that from the code.  :)

Comment: Yea, well you say access and it looks like you're defining it in your code, so I was confused. But looks like it works, but I have to do this `string Version = HttpContext.Current.Application["Version"].ToString()` , why won't it keep it's same data type?

Comment: Nvm, its an object, I guess I can give it properties how I want.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        int Version = (int)HttpContext.Application["Version"];
        return View();
    }
}
```

and Global:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    Application.Add("Version", 1); // I want to add this
}
```

I think that you can get HttpContext only from actions and views